# RestKit: mapping of dynamic attribute (not a NSDictionary as in the example)

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I'm using RestKit in my iOS project, and figured non-trivial problem and can't find solution for it.

I have a json:

```
[{
    "name": "restkit", 
    "downloads": 2
},
{
    "name": "restkit", 
    "rating": 10.0
}]
```

and data model: Model.h

```
@interface Model : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * key;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * value;
@end
```

Those JSON objects loaded in one array, and one of the attributes is a "dynamic" attribute.
After mapping performed in a RestKit I want to be able to have 2 records:

```
name: "restkit", key: "downloads", value: 2
name: "restkit", key: "rating", value: 10.0
```

Question: how to map JSON in the beginning into 2 NSObjects as shown in the example above?

This is how I initialize mapping using RestKit and firing requests:

```
// during app initialization I setup mappings:

RKObjectMapping *modelMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Model class]];
[metricDataMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];

...... -- something should go here to support that dynamic stuff

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:metricDataMapping];

// in the view controller when loading data
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:url usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader){
    loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass: [MetricData class]];

    loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray * objects){
        self.dataArray = objects;
    };
}];
```

The problem, is that keys "downloads" and "rating" are dynamic, and it could be any word. I need to parse that 'on-the-fly' and show in UI.
Restkit does support such behavior, but only for nested dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry, added exact question I have.

Comment: Any reson for downvoting both answers? They're forrect and good answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did use key-value validation on the model triggered by RestKit to set correct metric key and value to the generic key I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dynamically named properties using key-value coding. After you had made an NSDictionary out of the JSON, do this:

```
[self setValue:[dictionary objectForKey:@"downloads"] forKey:@"downloads"];
```

etc.

Comment: any clue how to plug this in RestKit's Object Mapping?

Comment: @thaold what do you mean by it exactly?